# i am trying to make a discord bot using discord.js and im making an even handler but im getting this error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Client.client.loadEvents (/Users/jacobzaldivar/Desktop/bot/index.js:21:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jacobzaldivar/Desktop/bot/index.js:23:8)
(base) jacobzaldivar@jacobs-mbp bot %
```

here's my code if you need it

```js
const bot = require("..")
const { getFiles } = require("../util/functions")

module.exports = (bot, reload) => {
    const {client} = bot

    let events = getFiles("../events/", ".js")

    if (events.length === 0){
        console.log("No events to load")
    }

    events.forEach((f, i) => {
        if (reload)
            delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../events/${f}`)]
        const event = require(`../events/${f}`)
        client.events.set(event.name, event)

        if (!reload)
            console.log(`${i + 1}. ${f} loaded`)
    })

    if (!reload)
        initEvents(bot)

}

function triggerEventHandler(bot, event, ...args)
    const {client} = bot

    try {
        if (client.events.has(event))
            client.events.get(event).run(bot, ...args)
        else
            throw new Error(`Event ${event} does not exist`)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(err)
    }
function initEvents(bot) {
    const {client} = bot

    client.on("ready", () => {
        triggerEventHandler(bot, "ready")
    })
}
```

Comment: Typo, missing parentheses (`{}`) after the `triggerEventHandler` function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing some formatting, indicated below.

```js
const bot = require("..")
const { getFiles } = require("../util/functions")

module.exports = (bot, reload) => {
    const {client} = bot

    let events = getFiles("../events/", ".js")

    if (events.length === 0){
        console.log("No events to load")
    }

    events.forEach((f, i) => {
        if (reload)
            delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../events/${f}`)]
        const event = require(`../events/${f}`)
        client.events.set(event.name, event)

        if (!reload)
            console.log(`${i + 1}. ${f} loaded`)
    })

    if (!reload)
        initEvents(bot)

}

function triggerEventHandler(bot, event, ...args) { //missing the {
    const {client} = bot

    try {
        if (client.events.has(event))
            client.events.get(event).run(bot, ...args)
        else
            throw new Error(`Event ${event} does not exist`)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(err)
    }
} //missing the }

function initEvents(bot) {
    const {client} = bot

    client.on("ready", () => {
        triggerEventHandler(bot, "ready")
    })
}
```